# Angular Material Input Select All on Click?

Tags: javascript, angular, input, material-design, selectall

Pretty straight-forward question. When I click on an input field I want to select-all the text so when I start typing it over-writes what was previously there. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Seems the following should work:

```
<input matInput (click)="$event.target.select()">
```

[**Example**](https://ng-run.com/edit/XvntAezOUWnYqIZyGwe2)

Comment: Indeed it does! ty

Comment: I realize the question asked specifically for when someone "clicks" on it... but I think it would be better to do with on focus: `(focus)="$event.target.select()"` That way if you are clicking around inside the field to move a cursor you wont end up re-selecting everything.

Answer (score 8):

What worked best for me is **onfocus="this.select()"**

```html
<input matInput onfocus="this.select()">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular material 1.x, you can use `md-select-on-focus`

```
<md-input-container>
  <label>Auto Select</label>
  <input type="text" md-select-on-focus>
</md-input-container>
```

This link can help you [md-select-on-focus](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.7/api/directive/mdSelectOnFocus)

Comment: FYI: This is AngularJS, Angular2 does not have this